# eBoarding passes of all family members on a single smartphone?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security

Family (2 adults and 2 children) booked DE->ES, online check-in done online. My wife has her boarding pass on her smartphone. On my smartphone, I have my own eBoarding pass as well as the children's.

It it at all possible that I show my smartphone 3 times (one time for each family member's boading pass) during the various check where one has to present it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I do it myself when traveling with colleagues when we're on the same reservation. Just tell the security/airline agent you have all their boarding passes on your phone, as if you checked in using their own app, they sometimes can navigate between them faster than you.